# Android UI design for Windows

Tags: windows, software-development, gui, user-interface

Is there any good app to design *Android UI*? I mean with the same UI elements as on Android.

It would be nice if there is app the same as the one integrated into *Android Studio*.

- uses the Android controls (i.e. with same appearance and, desirable, same naming)
- [ desirable ]  generates XML-files in format using in Android layout-files (so I can use this files without modifying them)
- works not slow

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. E.g. you should explicitly list all requirements (only "GUI" and "Android" is far too broad – and what's "good" is rather subjective aka "opinion based").

Comment: I told that the best would be app the same as the *editor* integrated in *Android Studio*. Isn't it enough? Or should I describe how the *editor* looks like?

Comment: Asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.